# How to sync a private fork?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, clone, git-fork

I want to create a private fork of a public repository and keep it up to date with the commits in the public one.

I tried to create a fork of the public repository. After that I was not able to make it private and found out that I will have to clone it.

The advice I found online was in regards to a public fork so I decided to clone it.

When I cloned it and made it private I found that there was no way to compare it with the public repository.

I tried to make my clone public but even that did not change anything.

So how can I set up a private fork/clone of a public repository and push the changes made to the public repository to my private fork/clone?

Comment: Clone and make a new branch that is not pushed to origin. That way you can just add stuff locally and no one will see it but you can still pull from origin.

Comment: If you are looking to automate the syncing of the fork, then you should have a look at this [GitHub App](https://github.com/apps/pull)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter, if your project is a private fork, or not. Forks are just repositories -- private, or not.

What you would typically do is, you'll create a fork and then in it, you'll work on feature branches bases off it's `master`. You will then push your branch to your fork and create a pull request against the upstream (the project that you've forked from). Once this pull request gets merged (or, you'd like to get the most recent changes from the upstream), you'll replace your `master` with the remote's, by fetching it and rebasing.

We re-worked Atlassian's article on Git Merge Vs. Rebase a bit for our project on Github. Have a look at [this page](https://strongbox.github.io/developer-guide/git/rebase-vs-merge.html). I hope it helps and answers your question!

Comment: Does this answer change if the private fork is hosted on github? or in otherwords, how would someone create a private fork on github and then be able to merge with the original public repo when changes occur there?